# Как проверить permission SYSTEM_OVERLAY_WINDOW?

Tags: java, android

Как проверить, разрешил ли пользователь использовать данную функцию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, нет такого permission `SYSTEM_OVERLAY_WINDOW`, есть `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`.

Во-вторых, если у вас `targetSdkVersion` 23 или выше, и используете Андроид 6.0+, то ваше приложение не получит этот permission изначально. Вызовите `Settings.canDrawOverlays()`, чтобы увидеть, есть ли у вас permission, и используйте `ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION`, чтобы отправить пользователя в Настройки, если их нет.

Отсюда:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32652625/3841429